# Create a simple screen widget with button which performs onClick?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I am trying to make a homescreen widget with a single Button which calls a method to perform some calculations using onClick.

I have googled it but only found the widgets calling specific activities .I dont want to call a activity just use the widget onscreen.

Anyone good at this could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget is just a View it has to be supported by a backend provider / service. You can do your calculations in the service

Comment: can u help me with some tutorial?

Comment: You mean a generic tutorial on Widget?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/index.html